# Difference between properties and fields in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Can somebody explain me what exactly is the difference between:

```
@interface PersistenceViewController : UIViewController { 
    UITextField *field1; 
    UITextField *field2; 
    UITextField *field3;
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field1; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field2; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field3;
```

and

```
@interface PersistenceViewController : UIViewController { 
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field1; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field2; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field3;
```

They both seem to work the same way.

Comment: check your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681117/what-are-the-diffs-between-iboutlet-as-property-or-as-variable